# Benefit to Static Final String in Request Param?

Tags: spring-mvc

I recently saw code like:

```
public String myMethodHere(@RequestParam(PARAM_FOO_ID) Integer fooId, 
                           Model model) {
  //some implementation
}

private static final String PARAM_FOO_ID = "fooId";
```

Is there a benefit in making a request param a static final String?

I didn't see it referenced anywhere else on SO and the examples in the Spring docs don't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not benefit in terms of performance as strings are interned anyway. But this way, it is more maintainable.

If you have several controller methods that accepts `"fooId"` as request parameter, you can just reuse `PARAM_FOO_ID` in all those controllers. Then if the client side decides to change the request parameter to send to your rest endpoint, all it takes is just a change to the value of `PARAM_FOO_ID` then your controller is ready to accommodate those changes.

Comment: Ok, seems like a negligible benefit to me (added lines of code, having to look up the request parameters when debugging)